# Whats wrong is with the code? Its giving me a run time error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
var names = ['Atlanta', 'Georgia', 'USA'];

for (var i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
if (names[i] = '')
alert("Go Atlanta!");
alert("You rock!");
}
```

// Above code giving me a run time error.. please help

Comment: `if(names[i] == '')` and set you start index for the loop to `0`

Comment: I don't see a runtime error.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Why does your if not have brackets to surround the case?

It only runs the 1st line after it, which is fine. It just tends to be good practice to surround your cases with brackets

Also, in your if you are setting names[i] to ' '.

You need to use the double equals operator.
Change this:

```
if (names[i] = '')
```

To this:

```
if (names [i] == ' ')
```

Comment: Since the loop test is `i < names.length`, it will never go outside the array. It will just skip the first element.

Comment: You are right! I overlooked this.

Answer (score -1):

`var names = ['Atlanta', 'Georgia', 'USA'];`

Your code is messing up for many reasons.  You did not open your if statement with `{}` or close it.  Also `i` will never be `''`

**try this**

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        alert("Go Atlanta!");
        alert("You rock!");
    }
}
```

also since arrays are indexed at 0 you can't start your loop at 1

Comment: How do you know he wants both alerts when the name matches?

Comment: @Barmar how do I not?  The question wasn't about that..the question is "Whats wrong is with the code? Its giving me a run time error?"

Comment: `names[i]` will never be zero. Why are you comparing strings to a number?

Comment: Simply overlooked thanks.

Comment: Then ask what he's trying to do in a comment.

Comment: @Rafael - I can tell you that `if(names[i] = '')` is incorrect, since this will assign 0 to `names[i]` and not compare against `''` which I would assume his trying to do.

Comment: Look at it again @Cyclone and I don't need to ask a question about a question.  This is an answer.  If you personally have a question you can add your comment under his question.  Muchas gracias senor ;)

Comment: @Barmar funny how you downvote me as if my answer did not answer his question.  Which it clearly does. Explain to me why you downvoted me the two of you?

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer

Comment: Why was this question down voted?   This is how I would have answered it as well.  I would like to know why it was down-voted so I can learn too. Thanks